# MVC 3 Checkbox failing at model return value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I've got my Partial view :

```
@foreach (var checkbox in Model.TimeLimit)
{
    <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label(checkbox.Name)
    @Html.Hidden(checkbox.Id) 
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(c=>checkbox.IsChecked)
    </div>
}
```

I've got a ParentViewModel which contains :

```
public IEnumerable<URLTimeLimitViewModel> TimeLimit { get; set; }
```

and  URlTimelimitViewmodel contains :

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Id { get; set; }
public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
```

When I call submit button, Timelimit in ParentViewModel returns null, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your loop - the model binder cannot figure out what to bind the posted values to:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.TimeLimit.Count; i++)
{
  <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label(Model.TimeLimit[i].Name)
    @Html.Hidden(Model.TimeLimit[i].Id) 
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(c=>Model.TimeLimit[i].IsChecked)
  </div>
}
```

You'll also need to declare your `TimeLimit` property as something other than an IEnumerable, I'd recommend a generic List (LINQs ToList method is very convenient!):

```
public List<URlTimelimitViewModel> TimeLimit { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Better solution is EditorTemplate for URLTimeLimitViewModel

It will looks like this

```
@model URlTimelimitViewModel
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label(Model.Name)
    @Html.Hidden(Model.Id) 
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(c=>Model.IsChecked)
</div>
```

and write following code instead of "foreach"

```
@Html.EditorFor(x=> x.TimeLimit)
```